# Understanding relation R on sets of integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let  = ℤ and  be the relation defined by  = ℤ × ℤ − {(, ) |  ∈ }.

a. Identify the relation , i.e. give the name or symbol that is in common usage for this relation.

b. Find ^2 and prove your answer.

Comment: Where are your stuck? Do you have an answer to the first or second question and would like to verify it?

Comment: I really don't understand the question. Number 1 seems like a map from all integers to integers minus the reflexive relationship. But I don't know what name or symbol is expected for that. For number 2 I don't really understand the abstract nature of the problem. Normally I mentally map out the relation.

Comment: You need to understand what definition of a "relationship" is and what it means.

Comment: For part 1, it isn't really a *map* so much as it is a *relationship*.  It should absolutely be something you've heard of before... Note: $1$ is related to $2$, $1$ is related to $3$... in general $1$ is related to everything except $1$.  Similarly $2$ is related to everything except $2$ and so on...  Another hint... common relations in usage and their symbols are things like $=,\equiv,\leq,\subset,\subseteq,\mid,\nmid,\not\subset$... There is a symbol I didn't put in that list which you should have seen before which is applicable here.

Comment: $R$ is not a map. A binary relation on a set $S$ is just some (any) subset of $S\times S.$   For example, we usually write $x<y$ but to a set-theorist, the relation $<$ on $\mathbb Z$ is equal to the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb Z^2: \exists n\in \mathbb N\;(y=x+n)\}. $

Comment: As box cannot be both Z and a subset of ZxZ the question fails to make sense.  Also box in box violates foundations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what definition of a "relationship" is and what it means.

Let's get colloquial.

We can say something simple like "$a$ and $b$ are related if $b$ is two times $a$".  So $7$ and $14$ are related and $46$ and $92$ are related but $8$ and $15$ are not related and so on.  Also $14$ and $7$ are not related because the relationship is only one way.  The second number must be twice the first but not vice versa.

So how do we express the idea mathematically?  Not just how to express the idea that *one* set of $b = 2a$ but the idea of the *relationship*?

Well, sets.  $X \times Y$ is the set of all pairs $(x,y)$.  So we want all the pairs $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ where $x$ is related to $y$.

In this case we want $R\subset \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ where $R = \{(a,b)| b = 2*a\}$.

In other words $R$ is the set of all pairs of integers, where the integers are related in a certain way.  In math a "RELATION" is a set of ordered pairs where the pair have a certain condition.

In this case the relation is that $R = \{(a,b)| (a,b) \not \in \{(n,n)\}\}$ which can be written as $R = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \setminus \{(n,n)|n \in \mathbb Z\}$.

So $a$ and $b$ are related if $(a,b)$ is NOT in $\{(n,n)|n \in \mathbb Z\}$.

So what is a way of saying that in simple english?

Hint: maybe first would be, how would you describe the relation between $a$ and $b$ if $(a,b)$ WERE in $\{(n,n)|n \in \mathbb Z\}$?  So how would you describe it if they were not?